# Add active class to the menu item - not menu created with wordpress, custom menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a menu created with this code

```
                   <?php
                      $pages = get_pages('child_of= 8&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=asc&parent=8');
                      foreach($pages as $page) {  
                    ?>
                     <li><a href="<?php $permalink = get_permalink($page->ID);
                        echo $permalink ; ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

With this I got the Child Pages of Main about Page. And I need to add active class in this items depending on which page i am(menu created with code above).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress: Add active class to $parent\_title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23494502/wordpress-add-active-class-to-parent-title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that simply by use is_page() to test if the user visit the active page in your menu :

```
 <?php
 $pages = get_pages('child_of= 8&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=asc&parent=8');

 foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    if ( is_page( $page->ID ) ) {
        $active = 'class="active"';
    } else {
        $active = '';
    }
    echo '<li '.$active.'><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'.$page->post_title.'</a></li>';
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It is working but I am getting an error Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/ipoint99/public_html/imc/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 254

Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in /home/ipoint99/public_html/imc/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 272

Comment: can you help me to fix this @Vincent Bocquet?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the following line inside class=''

If(get_the_ID()==$page->ID) echo 'class="active"';

Comment: ID must be in caps and don't forget a space + the class attribute in your echo !

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `<li>` (or `<a>`, as you wish) tag:

```
<?php if ( get_the_ID() == $page->ID ) echo ' class="active"'; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you @Sebastien!It is also a solution